# Firebase usage stats seem inflated, and I'd like to understand why the following observable results in upwards of 70 reads

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, quota

Since Google has decided to charge for just about every single aspect of Firebase Firestore and Firebase Cloud function usage, I'd like to make every effort to ensure our code executes queries to Firestore as efficiently as possible.

I am in the process of doing some isolated tests, which I will post here as updates, to try and determine whether or not Firebase's usage statistics are accurate, but at first glance, something does not seem right.

How does the following observable, which gets instantiated inside of the constructor of my authentication service in an angular application at app launch, result in upwards of 70+ read requests?

I can confirm that no changes occurred to the data prior to instantiating this instance of this observable nor after.

We had waited for the usage to settle, and after approximately an hour of zero usage, we launched 1 instance of our application which initiates the following observable:

```
            this.auth$ = this.firebaseAuth.authState.pipe(
              switchMap((user) => {
                if(user) {
                  console.log("[auth service] user update:", user);
                  return this.firestore.doc(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
                } else {
                  console.log("[auth service] user not signed in");
                  return of(null);
                }
              })
            );
```

Once the application had loaded, we immediately closed it.

After approximately 5 minutes, we checked the usage statistics in the Firebase console and saw 70+ read requests added to our usage. Why?

### Update 1

As per comments below, and just as we had in-fact suspected, having the Firebase console open in a browser will result in additional strikes against our quota, however, this still does not explain 70+ read requests as a result of our initial test. Or, does it? How many reads will a typical database accrue from a view in the console? Without navigating around? Does it load data that is not in view? For example, a collection that is not selected?

Comment: Do you have the Firebase console open?

Comment: Yes. Does viewing the DB in the console also count against our quota?

Comment: Yes, always. That's why you have those extra reads.

Comment: Simply having the console open? We were not refreshing the page during this test and no data was written, which would cause the console to update, by the client nor through the console. At best shouldn't i have seen double or to give them the benefit of the doubt triple the reads? Why 70+?? We expected to see a total of 3 reads in our test.

Comment: The console behaves like any other client. Once you open the console, you are charged with a number of read operations that is equal with the number of elements that are apart of the first page.

Comment: Thank you for this information. As i wrote above, I intend to do some isolated testing. I will post those results here and with all you said in mind, we will be sure to close the console prior to testing.

Answer (score 2):

It's very common that people wonder where reads are coming from when they are actually just coming from the Firebase console.  The console displays data in real time as it changes in the database, and each of those changes is billed as a read when the console reflects the change, just like any other client app.

When you run your tests, you should not have the Firestore database viewer open.  You can have other parts of the console open, just not the one that can reflect database changes in real time.

Comment: Given that the console appears to function asynchronously, does the page load data that is not currently selected 'under the hood'? For example, when the console loads the page that displays the Firestore database, by default it selects the first collection in the list. What about the remaining top level collections that have not been selected? Do those load as well when the page loads? Or only when actually clicked/selected?

Comment: It only loads what's necessary for display.  If you don't choose to view any documents, then no documents are read.